# Angular ng test Module not found: Error: can't resolve

Tags: angular

I have started up this Angular project last week using the command `ng new [myProjectName]`. I generated the components using `ng g c [componentName]`, which have correctly generated every component with a `.spec.ts` file. I then, after implementing business logic, and writing some test code, say `ng test` to try to run the test code, but get a whole slew of errors.

All of these errors I get on the command line, are in the form : `Module not found : Error : can't resolve [someNodeJSDependency] in [someNodeJSLibFolder]`. The browser that's supposed to spawn, that's supposed to contain the output of the tests, fails to capture (it starts up two or three times, but blank, and then closes). ng then says it's giving up.

Screenshots of the errors:

[image][image]

The `package.json` of the project looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "open-source-roads-page",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.5.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.4.2"
  }
}
```

I tried saying `node rebuild` at the project root, but that didn't have any effect on these errors.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? I looked all over the internet for the answer(s) to this problem, including on here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8357 , and none of that worked. If you think I'm missing crucial information in my question, could you specify what you think is missing? If you think there's something wrong with this question, could you please specify what you think it is and why?

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same error after that i removed my node_modules folder and reinstalled the latest version of node.js, and it worked for me.